# I have conflict with master with a branch but does not conflict with peer and same branch

Tags: git

there is a wondering issue! `my branch name is development that has a conflict with master` and on the other hand, I have a branch as `production` name, `the development and production branches are same but one of them has a conflict with master and another one does not have a conflict with master`! I try sometimes through multiple solutions eventually, I didn't any rational reason for why occurring this issue. can anyone help me? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think that a merge just looks at the *current state* of the working tree in each branch. What's actually important the relative *histories* of these branches. And two different branches are very, very unlikely to have exactly the same history!

This is what a merge is:

1. A merge starts with Git calculating the **common point** from which the merging branches diverged: the *merge base*.

   <sub>**HINT:** If you are about to merge, or thinking about merging, and you would like to know what the merge base would be, ask Git! That's what the `git merge-base` command is for. If you're about to merge `develop` into `master`, say `git merge-base develop master` and you will be told the identifier of the commit where Git thinks these branches originally diverged.</sub>
2. Git then calculates **two diffs**: From the merge base to the end of the first branch, and from the merge base to the end of the second branch.

   <sub>**HINT:** If you are about to merge, and you'd like to see those two diffs, ask Git! If you are on `master` and you are about to merge `develop` into it, say `git diff develop...` and `git diff ...develop` to see the `master` diff and the `develop` diff, respectively.</sub>
3. To form the merge, Git **enacts *both* diffs** on the merge base.

   <sub>**HINT:** If Git can't figure out how to do that, that's a conflict.</sub>

So it is very very improbable — almost impossible, in real life — that the diffs when you merge B into A are the same as the diffs when you merge C into A. At the very least, the merge bases will be totally different, and thus the diff pairs will be totally different. Therefore, it is *perfectly* possible that merging B into A should get a conflict, but merging C into A does not. There is no surprise here. Every merge is its own operation, with its own merge base and its own diffs.

Comment: Most of this explanation is close to right, but the introductory paragraph is wrong and dangerously misleading.  Most details of the histories DO NOT matter.  What matters are three things: (1) the current state of the source branch; (2) the current state of the target branch (which matt wrongly claims is irrelevant); and (3) the state of the merge base.  Those are used to calculate the diffs described in step (2).  Step (3) actually involves those diffs being applied to the merge base (not HEAD, which would already have "our" changes applied)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Excellent, thanks, I'll modify accordingly.